# Cognos table inside table cell

Tags: cognos-10

I have a report that displays a table of information inside a cell of another table. When the report is exported to excel there are blank rows above and below the table, the report looks fine when in HTML. I cannot have these as they throw errors when being imported into another application. How can I make it so that the table is one cell and no extra lines these?

Answer (score 0):

Include that data in the outer list.  If you are using Cognos as an ETL tool (something it is NOT good at) you'll want to flatten the output.  Any formatting will cause you trouble downstream.

Excel format is probably not the best solution.  You'll want to send your report to Excel Data or CSV.

Comment: Cognos is the only option I have for ETL. Excel is what our vendor requires. I will move the data out and see if that works.

Comment: Did not work. I moved the hard coded values outside to their own table, other combinations of tables. nothing worked.